# Function overloading by generic list<T> problem

Tags: c#, list, generics

Hi I have got lots of code duplication in my repository domain for e.g.

```
public CommonModel GetLocations(IModelWithCurrentUser<xyz> model)
{
    var sqlParameters = SqlHelpers.GetReportSqlParameters(model);
    var outputParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "TotalCount", default(int) } };
    var result = _queryExecutor.QueryWithOutputParameters<Locations>(PermissionsQueries.GetLocations, sqlParameters, outputParameters);
    var totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(outputParameters["TotalCount"]);
    return RepositoryConverter.ToCommonDSModel(result, model.Content, totalCount);
}
```

I was trying to make a generic method like this:

```
public CommonModel GetSqlReport<T>(IModelWithCurrentUser<xyz> model, string queryName)
{
    var sqlParameters = SqlHelpers.GetReportSqlParameters(model);
    var outputParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "TotalCount", default(int) } };
    var result = _queryExecutor.QueryWithOutputParameters<T>(queryName, sqlParameters, outputParameters);
    var totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(outputParameters["TotalCount"]);
    return RepositoryConverter.ToCommonDSModel(result, model.Content, totalCount);
}
```

But unfortunately, I got an error while compiling the code: 
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List T' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List roles'  in method

```
  return RepositoryConverter.ToCommonDSModel(result, model.Content, totalCount);
```

The respoitoryConverter method ToCommonDSModel is overloading by list type here are some examples:

```
public static CommonModel ToCommonDSModel(List<Roles> data, xyz dtoModel, long itemsCount)
public static CommonModel ToCommonDSModel(List<Locations> data, xyz dtoModel, long itemsCount)
public static CommonModel ToCommonDSModel(List<abc> data, xyz dtoModel, long itemsCount)
```

My question is how can I remove my code duplication in my repository domain?

Comment: You can´t, unless `ToCommonDSModel` itself was generic. There is no compile-time conversion between a `List<T>` and a `List<abc>`, as there´s no relationship between `T` and `abc`, at least none the compiler knows about - which could be determined by a generic constraint.

Comment: Ok but If I have got ToCommonDSModel generic can I still overload it by the list object type?

Comment: You won´t need to, as there´s only a single method that works for every type that satisfies the generic constraint.

Comment: That however assumes your types even have anything in common and that method only bothers for those common members (an ID for instance, or a `Name` or whatever). If not there´s absolutely no reason to think about generics.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. So, unfortunately, I can't remove this duplicating code :( .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public CommonModel GetSqlReport<T>(IModelWithCurrentUser<xyz> model, string queryName)
{
    var sqlParameters = SqlHelpers.GetReportSqlParameters(model);
    var outputParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "TotalCount", default(int) } };
    var result = _queryExecutor.QueryWithOutputParameters<T>(queryName, sqlParameters, outputParameters);
    var totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(outputParameters["TotalCount"]);
    return RepositoryConverter.ToCommonDSModel<T>(result, model.Content, totalCount);
}

public static class RepositoryConverter
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Delegate> __map = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>()
    {
        { typeof(Roles), (Func<List<Roles>, xyz, long, CommonModel>)ToCommonDSModel },
        { typeof(Locations), (Func<List<Locations>, xyz, long, CommonModel>)ToCommonDSModel },
        { typeof(abc), (Func<List<abc>, xyz, long, CommonModel>)ToCommonDSModel },
    }
    public static CommonModel ToCommonDSModel<T>(List<T> data, xyz dtoModel, long itemsCount)
        => ((Func<List<T>, xyz, long, CommonModel>)__map[typeof(T)])(data, dtoModel, itemsCount);

    public static CommonModel ToCommonDSModel(List<Roles> data, xyz dtoModel, long itemsCount) => /* implementation here */;
    public static CommonModel ToCommonDSModel(List<Locations> data, xyz dtoModel, long itemsCount) => /* implementation here */;
    public static CommonModel ToCommonDSModel(List<abc> data, xyz dtoModel, long itemsCount) => /* implementation here */;
}
```

The secret sauce is to use the `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` to hold functions of different types which you retrieve based on the generic type `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks :D for a really good piece of code but on another forum, I found this way:

change

```
var result = _queryExecutor.QueryWithOutputParameters<T>(queryName, sqlParameters, outputParameters);
```

to

```
dynamic result = _queryExecutor.QueryWithOutputParameters<T>(queryName, sqlParameters, outputParameters);
```